# Normalize a dictionary of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, database-normalization, normalize

I'm learning to code and I'm still not very good at it. My problem is I have a Python dictionary of minerals and each mineral (the key) has another dictionary as value, where I can read the properties.
E.g.

```
"Quartz": {
"Zeff-2.94": 11.560477823722744,
"Rhoe": 7.968143490069414e+23
},
"Siderite": {
"Zeff-2.94": 20.242908072785397,
"Rhoe": 1.1265233868351479e+24
},
.....etc }
```

Then, I have to normalize between 0 and 1 all the "Zeff" values and all the "Rhoe" values in the "big minerals dictionary". I thought to write a loop, but it doesn't work:

```
import CommonMinerals_database 
import math 
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

norm_mineral_database = {}
for k in CommonMinerals_database.COMMON_MINERALS_DATABASE.keys(): 
    norm_mineral = COMMON_MINERALS_DATABASE[k] 
    Zeff_norm = normalize(norm_mineral["Zeff-2.94"])  
    rhoe_norm = normalize(norm_mineral["Rhoe"])
print(norm_mineral_database)
```

My goal would be to obtain another minerals dictionary (even it won't look like a "normal" python dictionary) where I can read the normalized properties.
Please, could you help me?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What error's if any are you getting and on what line?

Comment: ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=13.26645845673176.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension is easy, as a simplification I am assuming just 2 minerals, but it should work for a bigger dict. Not sure what kind of normalization you want to use, so modify the code if needed

```
import numpy as np

d = {"Quartz": {
"Zeff-2.94": 11.560477823722744,
"Rhoe": 7.968143490069414e+23
},
"Siderite": {
"Zeff-2.94": 20.242908072785397,
"Rhoe": 1.1265233868351479e+24
}}

a =  np.sum([d[key]["Zeff-2.94"] for key in d.keys()])
b = np.sum([d[key]["Rhoe"] for key in d.keys()])

new_dict = {key:{"Zeff_norm":d[key]["Zeff-2.94"]/a,"Rhoe_norm":d[key]["Rhoe"]/b} for key in d.keys()}
```

EDIT:
The case above is using the sum of the elements as norm .

If you want a min-max normalization [check this](https://learn.64bitdragon.com/articles/computer-science/data-processing/min-max-normalization) to see how to do it manually.

```
d = {"Quartz": {
"Zeff-2.94": 11.560477823722744,
"Rhoe": 7.968143490069414e+23
},
"Siderite": {
"Zeff-2.94": 20.242908072785397,
"Rhoe": 1.1265233868351479e+24
},
"Mineral3:":{
"Zeff-2.94":15,
"Rhoe":1e+24}}


min_Zeff = np.min([d[key]["Zeff-2.94"] for key in d.keys()])
max_Zeff = np.max([d[key]["Zeff-2.94"] for key in d.keys()])
range_Zeff = max_Zeff - min_Zeff

min_Rhoe = np.min([d[key]["Rhoe"] for key in d.keys()])
max_Rhoe = np.max([d[key]["Rhoe"] for key in d.keys()])
range_Rhoe = max_Rhoe - min_Rhoe

new_dict = {key:{"Zeff_norm":(d[key]["Zeff-2.94"] - min_Zeff)/range_Zeff,"Rhoe_norm":(d[key]["Rhoe"]-min_Rhoe)/range_Rhoe} for key in d.keys()}

print(new_dict)
```

or alternativately check [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np

d = {"Quartz": {
"Zeff-2.94": 11.560477823722744,
"Rhoe": 7.968143490069414e+23
},
"Siderite": {
"Zeff-2.94": 20.242908072785397,
"Rhoe": 1.1265233868351479e+24
},
"Mineral3:":{
"Zeff-2.94":15,
"Rhoe":1e+24}}

scaler = MinMaxScaler()

Zeff = [d[key]["Zeff-2.94"] for key in d]
Rhoe = [d[key]["Rhoe"] for key in d]

Zeff_norm = scaler.fit_transform(np.array(Zeff).reshape(-1,1)).T[0]
Rhoe_norm = scaler.fit_transform(np.array(Rhoe).reshape(-1,1)).T[0]

new_dict = {key:{"Zeff_norm":Zeff_norm[i],"Rhoe_norm":Rhoe_norm[i]} for i,key in enumerate(d.keys())}
print(new_dict)
```

Comment: Hi Lorenzo! Thank you very much! Just a question... you told me you are not sure about the normalization I need to accomplish. I actually would like to take the maximum and the minimum value of both Zeff and Rhoe in my dictonary and then normalize, obtaining values between 0 and 1 (e.g. the mineral having the bigger Zeff will be the 1 for this property). I try to run the code you suggest me and it seems great, but I have neither 0 nor 1. Is it not normal, isn't it? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I edited the answer. See if that works. Probably the first answer didn't work because your data has negative values, am I right?

Comment: Hi Lorenzo! Actually no, the data values are always positive; I tried your first answer and it seems to be perfect! Thank you so much for your help :-)